# Bios will not let me change Virtualisation to enabled. CPU does have the ability for virtualisation I have checked

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, virtualization

I am running Ubuntu VM from my VirtualBox on my Windows 10 Lenovo W530 machine. I am getting the following error when I try to start the VM.

> VT-x is disabled in the BIOS for all CPU modes
>   (VERR_VMX_MSR_ALL_VMX_DISABLED).

That makes sense so when I go into my BIOS and try to enable Virtualisation it does not let me change it from "disabled" to "enabled". Its like the option to even highlight it is greyed out.

Some forums have made mention that I need to disable Control Panel > Programs > Turn Windows features on or off > Hyper-V. This has not worked.

Is there anyone out there who might have an idea on why I cannot change Virtualisation to enabled on my BIOS. Any help would be much appreciated.

Will see if I can access the advanced settings of the Bios but <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> at start up.

Comment: What CPU do you have?

Comment: Intel Core i7-3720QM @ 2.60GHz. Its annoying but the virtualisation was working on this before.

Comment: Anybody have any idea on how I can fix this?

Comment: Think if I Ctrl+F1 will get me on to advanced settings and then I could hopefully change the values.

Comment: I actually suspect that a new image of windows 10 has somehow changed the entitlements on my BIOS and maybe that has affected it...